# Wifi Direct Support on iOS Devices

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi, iphone

I am getting a lot of conflicting information to this simple question.

Basically I need to understand which devices will support WiFi direct. Is this device specific or is this iOS specific?

Can I run a Wifi Direct App on say a iPhone 4s with iOS 7?

How about a iPad Mini and iOS 8?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically the device list is as follows, running iOS 7 or later:

- iPhone 5 or later
- iPad (4th generation or later)
- iPad mini
- iPod touch (5th generation)

That said, this is the compatibility list for AirDrop which uses WiFi Direct as of iOS 7. Your mileage may vary with apps that are not utilizing AirDrop for the WiFi Direct functionality.

Comment: Thanks Tubedogg. What I am trying to do is attached to a small embedded device using WiFi direct with an iPhone, and then I am hoping this device can send data using the iPhones cellular data connection to the Cloud. I am trying to write a Mobile App that creates this connection. In Android I can see the device, but I have not been able to see it in an iOS app...I am hoping this is possible with iOS.

Comment: @Remixed123 did you find an answer? The more I look into this the more it seems Apple does not allow for wifi-direct.